# RecyclerView тормозит при использовании ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, recyclerview

Давно писал приложение, в котором имеется RecyclerView. В него выводится список товаров. Разметку для карточки товара, на тот момент, накидал следующую:

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/catKod"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_kod"
                android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                tools:ignore="SpUsage"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/catName"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_name"
                tools:ignore="SpUsage"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgS"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/image_height"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription,NestedWeights" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tmpcena"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="0.001"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:text="@string/catcena"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_other"
                            tools:ignore="SpUsage"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/catCena"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="0.34"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_other_2"
                            tools:ignore="SpUsage"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/catSpeccena"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="3"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_other_2"
                            tools:ignore="SpUsage"/>

                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="0.34"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:text="@string/catostatok"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_other"
                            tools:ignore="SpUsage"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/catOstatok"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_other_2"
                            tools:ignore="SpUsage"/>
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="0.34"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:text="@string/catpart"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_other"
                            tools:ignore="SpUsage"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="0.34"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:text="@string/catkorob"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_other"
                            tools:ignore="SpUsage"/>
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/catPart"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_other_2"
                            tools:ignore="SpUsage"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/catKorob"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_other_2"
                            tools:ignore="SpUsage"/>
                    </TableRow>

                </TableLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/noemptyL"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bMinus"
                        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_size"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_size"
                        android:onClick="bCount"
                        android:text="@string/catminus"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_btn"
                        tools:ignore="SpUsage"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/catCountSale"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_size_edit"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_size"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="6"
                        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_btn"
                        tools:ignore="SpUsage"/>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bPlus"
                        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_size"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_size"
                        android:onClick="bCount"
                        android:text="@string/catplus"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_btn"
                        tools:ignore="SpUsage"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/emptyL"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/addBasket"
                        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_size_basket"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_size"
                        android:onClick="bCount"
                        android:text="@string/add_basket"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_btn"
                        tools:ignore="SpUsage"/>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Здесь размещается много элементов карточки товара, и т.к. некоторые приходилось выравнивать между собой я долгое время шаманил с весом каждого элемента или слоя, а так же использовал таблицу для выравнивания.

Сейчас дошли руки оптимизировать приложение, захотелось убрать кучу макетов под разные экраны и использовать один универсальный ConstraintLayout. Получилась следующая разметка:

**test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    app:cardElevation="3dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/catKod"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_other"
            tools:ignore="SpUsage"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/catName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_name"
            tools:ignore="SpUsage"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/catKod" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgS"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/catName"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/nophoto"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription,HardcodedText" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tmpcena"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="@string/catcena"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_other"
            tools:ignore="SpUsage"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgS" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/catCena"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_other_2"
            tools:ignore="SpUsage"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tmpcena"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgS" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/catSpeccena"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_other_2"
            tools:ignore="SpUsage"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/catCena"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/catCena" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textostatok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/catostatok"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_other"
            tools:ignore="SpUsage"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/catCena" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/catOstatok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_other_2"
            tools:ignore="SpUsage"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textostatok"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/catCena" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textmipart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/catpart"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_other"
            tools:ignore="SpUsage"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textostatok"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/catOstatok" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textcorobka"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/catkorob"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_other"
            tools:ignore="SpUsage"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.329"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textmipart"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/catOstatok" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/catPart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_other_2"
            tools:ignore="SpUsage"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textmipart"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textmipart" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/catKorob"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_other_2"
            tools:ignore="SpUsage"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textcorobka"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textcorobka" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/noemptyL"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/catPart"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/catPart">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bMinus"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_size"
                android:onClick="bCount"
                android:text="@string/catminus"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_btn"
                tools:ignore="SpUsage"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/catCountSale"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_size_edit"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_size"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="6"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_btn"
                tools:ignore="Autofill,LabelFor,SpUsage" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bPlus"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_size"
                android:onClick="bCount"
                android:text="@string/catplus"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_btn"
                tools:ignore="SpUsage" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/emptyL"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/catPart"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/catPart">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/addBasket"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_size_basket"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_size"
                android:onClick="bCount"
                android:text="@string/add_basket"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_btn"
                tools:ignore="SpUsage" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

LinearLayout **noemptyL** и **emptyL** скрываются и отображаются в зависимости от того, добавлен товар в корзину или нет.

Применяю эту разметку к RecyclerView и тестирую на реальных устройствах. При прокрутке карточек приложение начинает работать с большими тормозами, хотя если вернуть старую разметку - все становится нормально, и никаких подвисаний/фризов нет.

Почему так происходит, и как можно ускорить работу RecyclerView с ConstraintLayout в моем случае?

**UPD** Картинки

Товар не добавлен в корзину
[image: Товар не добавлен в корзину]
Товар добавлен в корзину
[image: Товар добавлен в корзину]

**UPD2:**

Отключил весь код в onBindViewHolder, убрал CardView, убрал вложенные слои, убрал все кнопки, оставил только Guideline, ImageView и TextView (статичный) - остались фризы при скролле.

Убрал Guideline - сделал все объекты жесткими по размерам, привязал все последовательно, сделал привязку элементов только к краям экрана - фризы при скролле.

Возвращаю на первоначальный макет, включаю весь код - ни одного фриза, даже если очень быстро скроллить.

Comment: два вложенных LinearLayout это точно совершенно лишнее, ConstraintLayout - одноуровневый контейнер, других контенеров в нем быть не должно. Добавьте скриншот, как все должно выглядеть

Comment: @pavlofff согласен, но пока не знаю как это сделать лучше, совсем не хочется делать 2 разметки для двух разных состояний карточки. Добавил скрины.

Comment: @pavlofff можно узнать где написано что ConstraintLayout одноуровневый контейнер, и что других контейнеров быть не должно?

Comment: @yno7 вот [здесь написано](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/), прямо в первом абзаце. так же в презентации об этом говорилось, что пришло время покончить с вложенными иерархиями ...

Comment: @pavlofff да увидел, мне кажется все таки не стоит так уверено говорить что он одноуровневый и что в нем не должен быть других контейнеров. Там все же речь идет о возможностях контейнера.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev в ConstraintLayout виджеты можно [объеденять в группы](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Group) и управлять сразу всей группой, например видимостью такой группы, оборачивать виджеты в контейнер при этом не требуется. [пример](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/491-urok-182-constraintlayout-chain-weight-barrier-group.html)

Comment: @pavlofff "если вы разберетесь, как выполняется расчет такой многоуровневой разметки, то вам уже не так сильно захочется за нее заступаться". Могу вам сказать тоже самое) Говорить что это CL оптимизированее вложенной иерархи не стоит вовсе. Это не таблетка от всех болезней, и можно привести уйму случаев когда CL проиграет вложенным иерархиям или когда внутри него будет уместно использовать контейнер. Не уверен что стоит дальше продолжать разговор об этом, просто хотел вам сказать чтоб вы не вносили столь радикальные определения.

Comment: @Andrey Mihalev а можно код из onBindViewHolder()?

Comment: @pavlofff - попробую обернуть в группу.

Comment: @yno7, я пробовал отключать всё что есть в onBindViewHolder, даже фото и обработчики кнопок - результат нулевой, тормоза оставались, поэтому я не стал указывать его в вопросе. Проведу еще ряд тестов, и выложу все что есть.

Comment: попробуйте избавиться от контейнеров LinearLayout в ConstraintLayout. в теории это должно повысить производительность. Также у вас в разметке несколько TextView, которые являются одними из самых прожорливых. Отключите hyphenation для TextView, что приблизительно повысит скорость отрисовки в 2 раза. Подробнее https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXqwRhjd7b4

Comment: @yno7 похоже ConstraintLayout, в моем случае, действительно проигрывает даже первоначальной реализации.

Comment: а вашего приложения нету на гитхабе/гитлабе случайно?

Comment: @yno7, нет. Да и код там ужасный. Чтобы его показывать надо сначала все причесать, привести к человеческому виду, чтобы не стыдно было. А у меня на это времени пока нет.

Comment: а в чем выражаются эти фризы? медленная прокрутка, заметная прорисовка айтема, "замирания" на каждом, например, 10 айтеме или как выглядит? просто у меня есть айтемы на CL, каких то проблем я не замечал, они не такие нагруженные, как первый вариант, но все же несколько сложнее последнего (где без гайдлайна и всего)

Comment: @pavlofff, прокручивание происходит рывками. Не важно сколько элементов прокрутил. Если сделать ImageView и 3-5 элемента, то проблем не возникает, скроллит нормально без рывков. Но проблема в том, что у меня элементов больше. Поэтому и говорю, что для моего случая видимо CL не подходит, надо менять дизайн.