# Зависание Ui потока при отрисовке RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-sdk, оптимизация

При установке данных на RecyclerView происходит зависание UI Потока, нету анимации добавления айтема и подзависает сильно анимация SwipeRefresh, вроде как каких либо сложных элементов нету.

Установка данных идет через DiffUtill который в свою очередь вроде как должен сделать все с анимацией:

```
   viewModel.newsResult.observe(this, Observer {
        val rdNews: DiffUtillBaseModel = DiffUtillBaseModel(adapter.list, it)
        val result = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(rdNews)

        adapter.setData(it)
        result.dispatchUpdatesTo(adapter)
    })
```

Установка состояния для swipeRefresh:

```
viewModel.isLoading.observe(this, Observer {
        binding.swipeRefresh.isRefreshing = it
    })
```

Адаптер листа:

```
    sealed class RVNews
{
   class Adapter(): RecyclerView.Adapter<RVNews.ViewHolder>()
   {
       var list: List<News> = listOf()

       var clickInterface: Clickable? = null

       fun setClicked(clickable: Clickable)
       {
           clickInterface = clickable
       }

       fun setData(list: List<News>)
       {
           this.list = list
       }

       override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder
       {
           return ViewHolder(DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), R.layout.item_news, parent, false),
               clickInterface)
       }

       override fun getItemCount(): Int
       {
           return list.size
       }

       override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int)
       {
           holder.bind(list.get(position))
       }

       override fun onViewRecycled(holder: ViewHolder)
       {
           super.onViewRecycled(holder)

           val glide = Glide.with(holder.binding.root)

           glide.clear(holder.binding.img)
           glide.clear(holder.binding.ava)

           holder.binding.chipGroup.removeAllViews()

           Log.d("RV_LIVE","View Clear")
       }
   }

    class ViewHolder(val binding: ItemNewsBinding, val clickInterface: Clickable?): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
    {
        fun bind(item: News)
        {
            item.photo?.let {
                ImgHelper.loadImg(binding.img, it)
            }

            item.authorAvatar?.let {
                ImgHelper.loadImg(binding.ava, it)
            }

            binding.name.text = item.authorName
            binding.date.text = item.createdAt.getDateDDMMMMYYY()

            binding.title.text = item.title
            binding.desc.text = item.shortDescription

            binding.chipGroup.removeAllViews()

            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(binding.root.context)

            item.tags.forEach {
                binding.chipGroup.addView(createSubChip(layoutInflater, binding.chipGroup, it.title, it.getBgColor(binding.root.context)))
            }

            binding.root.setOnClickListener {
                clickInterface?.let {
                    it.clickItem(item)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    interface Clickable
    {
        fun clickItem(item: News)
    }
}
```

И верстка самого айтема:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="news"
            type="com.fasd.dev.reboot.data.model.News" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="384dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

        <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:riv_corner_radius="8dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:riv_mutate_background="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:foreground="@drawable/shape_fg_news_rounded" />

        <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
            style="@style/ImageAvatar"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:id="@+id/ava"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Анна Ковальт"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/name"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ava"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ava"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/ava"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="4dp"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/shape_circle_w"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/dot"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/name"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/name"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/name"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5 декабря 2019"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/date"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/dot"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/dot"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/dot"/>

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextTitleNews"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/desc"
            android:text="Дольше живет тот, кто осознает свое счастье"/>

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextDescNews"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/chip_group"
            android:text="Научившись замечать хорошее в своей жизни, мы делаем ее гораздо более приятной и, как утверждают ученые, долгой"/>

        <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            style="@style/SubChipGroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/chip_group"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                style="@style/SubFilterChip"
                android:text="Осознанность"
                app:chipSurfaceColor="#800093FC" />

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                style="@style/SubFilterChip"
                android:text="Начало"
                app:chipBackgroundColor="#804CD964"
                app:chipSurfaceColor="#004CD964" />

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                style="@style/SubFilterChip"
                android:text="Становление"
                app:chipBackgroundColor="#80FC0097"
                app:chipSurfaceColor="#00FC0097" />

        </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            style="@style/FirstIcnBtn"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/union_btn"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_union"/>

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            style="@style/FirstIcnBtn"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/like_btn"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/union_btn"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_like"
            android:paddingTop="9dp"
            android:text="150" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Скорее всего это с `DiffUtil` связано. Возможно, его использование можно/нужно в другой поток вынести

Comment: @ЮрийСПб При использование notifyDataSetChanged ситуация к сожалению не меняется.

Comment: Хм... Попробуйте закоментировать всё в `ViewHolder#bind()` - если лаги исчезнут, значит там проблема. После этого попробуйте по одной строке раскоментировать и смотреть когда начнутся лаги. Больше ничего такого в коде, вроде, не видать.

Comment: [Похожий вопрос у меня был](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/913509/), решение я так и не нашел. Пришлось отказаться от `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: @Андрей Скорее всего проблема в `ConstraintLayout` как и пишет Андрей. `ConstraintLayout` в сочетании с `RecyclerView` это торможение, особенно это чувствуется на старых устройствах. Так что попробуйте вместо `ConstraintLayout` использовать `LinearLayout`.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev А почему так происходит ? Разве не должно быть наоборот ?

Comment: @McDaggen  А почему так происходит ? Разве не должно быть наоборот ?